# Python: Retrieving "NULL" from nested dictionary when key is missing

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I'm processing some data that comes from nested dictionaries (over an API).
I want to store the data into a database, I use `psycopg2` to do so and I wrote some code to put together my SQL statements ("INSERT INTO mytable...").

Everything runs fine so far, but every now and then the data does not have all the required information. In rare cases one of the keys is missing. This causes my script to crash.
So I tried some kind of error handling, because in the case of missing data, I just want to have "NULL" instead.

But, I only got it to work when I repeated the "try/except block" for every single piece of data. Isn't there an easier way to do this?

Here's an example:

```
mydict = {'name': {'firstname': 'Peter', 'surname': 'Pan'}, 'contact': {'hometown': 'Neverland', 'phone': '123-456'}}

sql = f"INSERT INTO mytable(firstname, surname, phone)\nVALUES\n("
sql += f"'{mydict['name']['firstname']}',"
sql += f"'{mydict['name']['surname']}',"
sql += f"'{mydict['contact']['phone']}');"
```

For the case of missing data I tried:

```
mydict = {'name': {'firstname': 'Peter', 'surname': 'Pan'}, 'contact': {'hometown': 'Neverland'}}

sql = f"INSERT INTO mytable(firstname, surname, phone)\nVALUES\n("
try:
    sql += f"'{mydict['name']['firstname']}',"
except KeyError:
    sql += 'NULL'
try:
    sql += f"'{mydict['name']['surname']}',"
except KeyError:
    sql += 'NULL'
try:
    sql += f"'{mydict['contact']['phone']}');"
except KeyError:
    sql += f"NULL);"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I avoid KeyError when working with dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46024562/how-do-i-avoid-keyerror-when-working-with-dictionaries)

Comment: The duplicate doesn't answer how to handle the case of nested dictionaries, so I don't think this is an appropriate dupe target.

Comment: Independently, manually building SQL queries is a bad idea. You should use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead to avoid [SQL injection](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: That's right, I had already found different solution like using .get(), but I had now idea how to be prepared for every possible missing key regardless of its level in the dictionary.
@BrokenBenchmark: Okay, good to know, I will have a look at the prepared statements!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to return `"NULL"` when a requested key doesn't exist. To transform the dictionary, you can use:

```
from collections import defaultdict
mydict = {
    'name': {'firstname': 'Peter', 'surname': 'Pan'},
    'contact': {'hometown': 'Neverland', 'phone': '123-456'}
}

mydict = defaultdict(
    lambda: defaultdict(lambda: "NULL", {}),
    {k: defaultdict(lambda: "NULL", v) for k, v in mydict.items()}
)

print(mydict["name"]["firstname"])
print(mydict["name"]["missing_key"])
print(mydict["missing_key"]["surname"])
```

This outputs:

```
Peter
NULL
NULL
```

---

If you only want to avoid using `try/except` blocks, you can also chain calls to `.get()`. For example, you can do:

```py
sql += mydict.get("name", {}).get("firstname", "NULL")
```

in place of:

```py
try:
    sql += f"'{mydict['name']['firstname']}',"
except KeyError:
    sql += 'NULL'
```

The second parameter to `.get()` is a fallback for cases where the key doesn't exist. For the first call, we return an empty dictionary, which allows us to fall back to the `"NULL"` default on the second call to `.get()`.

Comment: Works fine, thank you! I tried different variations of .get(), but had no idea how to use this in the case of a dictionary with two or more levels. Now I can even handle my dict that is nested up to four times.
I will also check out collections.defaultdict!